# Why is Devart Entity Developer is removing the underscore in property names?

Tags: c#, devart

I am using devart entity developer and try to generate a model Database First approach with Fluent mapping. I would like to retain my table column names as is in classes and model store. My column names are having underscore in between example: PROP_NAME. But the classes are created with property name as PROPNAME in configuration file and in model class. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the property to avoid this scenario in Model settings of the edml.

Remove underscore check box should be unchecked in both Class and model store sections.

Comment: this is historical answrer ;)